# Bug in isodata?: German short date with horizontal spaces after periods

Tags: spacing, isodate

Is there a bug in the `isodate` package? When I switch to `\shortdate` with the option `german`, horizontal spaces occur after the periods:

```
\documentclass{article}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\usepackage[german]{isodate}
    \shortdate
\begin{document}
30.04.17 (manual)\\\today\,(isodate)
\end{document}
```

[image: isodate spacing bug]

Is this known/wanted? I certainly would rather not have the spaces after the periods. Would it be better to use `datetime2`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is wanted, see the documenentation. You can change it like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\usepackage[german]{isodate}
    \shortdate
\daymonthsepgerman{}\monthyearsepgerman{}{}
\begin{document}
30.04.17 (manual)\\\today\,(isodate)
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Interesting spelling of `documentation` (`documenentation`).