# biblatex: german short date format (with periods) – remove unwanted additional space after periods

Tags: biblatex, date

There is a small space after every period in the German short date (as well as `urldate` and every other `date`) of `biblatex`:

[image: MWE]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{literature.bib}
  @online{foobar,
    url = {https://www.foo.bar},
    date = {2019-09-24},
    urldate = {2019-09-24},
  }
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[date=short]{biblatex}
\bibliography{literature.bib}

\begin{document}
  \nocite{foo,foobar}
  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Why? How do I get rid of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is indeed a `\thinspace` after every period in the German short date of `biblatex`. It is inserted on purpose in `german.lbx`:

```
  \protected\def\mkbibdateshort#1#2#3{%
    \iffieldundef{#3}
      {}
      {\mkdayzeros{\thefield{#3}}\adddot
       \iffieldundef{#2}{}{\thinspace}}%
    \iffieldundef{#2}
      {}
      {\mkmonthzeros{\thefield{#2}}%
       \iffieldundef{#1}
         {}
         {\iffieldundef{#3}{/}{\adddot\thinspace}}}%
    \iffieldbibstring{#1}
      {\bibstring{\thefield{#1}}}
      {\dateeraprintpre{#1}\mkyearzeros{\thefield{#1}}}}%
```

Having found out this, I searched for it in the biblatex doc, without success.
Then I was searching here and found the following:
[Bug in isodata?: German short date with horizontal spaces after periods](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/367524/bug-in-isodata-german-short-date-with-horizontal-spaces-after-periods).
So, the package `isodate` seems to do the same thing.

Ulrike Fischer advised to look into the docs, so I did.
Et voilà:

> The spacings for the numerical formats in the German language (24. 12.
>   2000 resp. 24. 12. 00) were taken from the Duden [2] and are the
>   defaults when using one of the German derivatives. [...]
>
> References
>
> [2]  DUDEN Band 1.  Die deutsche Rechtschreibung.  21. Auflage,  Dudenverlag, Mannheim, Germany, 1996.

I haven't found a similar advice in the online version https://duden.de,
nor do I like the spacing.

To get rid of it, just redefine the `\mkbibdateshort` from `german.lbx`:

[image: MWE]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{literature.bib}
  @online{foobar,
    url = {https://www.foo.bar},
    date = {2019-09-24},
    urldate = {2019-09-24},
  }
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[date=short]{biblatex}
\bibliography{literature.bib}

\DefineBibliographyExtras{ngerman}{% from german.lbx
  \protected\def\mkbibdateshort#1#2#3{%
  \iffieldundef{#3}
  {}
  {\mkdayzeros{\thefield{#3}}\adddot
    \iffieldundef{#2}{}{}}%<-\thinspace removed
  \iffieldundef{#2}
  {}
  {\mkmonthzeros{\thefield{#2}}%
    \iffieldundef{#1}
    {}
    {\iffieldundef{#3}{/}{\adddot}}}%<-\thinspace removed
  \iffieldbibstring{#1}
  {\bibstring{\thefield{#1}}}
  {\dateeraprintpre{#1}\mkyearzeros{\thefield{#1}}}}%
}

\begin{document}
  \nocite{foo,foobar}
  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Wouldn't it be neat if this became easier..?

Comment: https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/891 The question is what would be a good interface.

Comment: @moewe Thanks for the link, I wasn't aware of that. Maybe one should consider to put the info from the `isodate` documentation into the biblatex documentation as well?